# JWT verification fails with ESPv2 with Firebase authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-gateway

I was building authenticated Cloud functions using[Cloud functions with ESPV2](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) and [Firebase authentication and API Management](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase). Once I got the JWT token from firebase after authentication, I tried `curl` to the link with the token in `Authorization` as `Bearer`. I got 'JWT verification fails' when I tried in postman. I got 'Bad Request' when I tried it from my client application. Other than the setup mentioned in the links, do I need to do anything extra before I make the request?

**Update with more details as requested**

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: My API Endpoints
  description: My API Endpoints
  version: 1.0.0
host: myapi-abcdefg.a.run.app
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
securityDefinitions:
  firebase:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/fan-demand"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-audiences: "my-google-project-id"
paths:
  /getevents:
    get:
      summary: Get Events
      operationId: getevents
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://us-central1-my-google-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/getevents
        protocol: h2
      security:
        - firebase: []
      responses:
        "200":
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
        "403":
          description: Failed to authenticate
```

After deploying this service, I get the id token from `Firebase` using the  `getIdToken()` method in the `Firebase` Dart SDK. The JWT token is in the Header.payload.tail format. Then I added the token in the `Authorization` header with `Bearer`  + id token and I get the following response.
[image]

**Update:**
I tried the new API Gateway product using https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-firebase instead of ESP.

**My configuration:**

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: My API Endpoints
  description: My API Endpoints
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
securityDefinitions:
  firebase:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/my-project"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-audiences: "my-project"
paths:
  /getevents:
    get:
      summary: Get Events
      operationId: getevents
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/getevents
      security:
        - firebase: []
      responses:
        "200":
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
        "403":
          description: Failed to authenticate
```

**Client Side Code:**
Client side is developed in dart and `user` here is a firebase auth object from https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/getIdToken.html

```
user.getIdToken().then((token) async {
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
          'https://mygateway/getevents'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      });
  print('Token : ${token}');
  print(response.body);
});
```

I got the response

> 403 Forbidden - Your client does not have permission to get URL

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  There should be enough information that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's hard to answer without any inputs (configuration, code, full error trace,...)

Comment: The issue could be generated by a number of reasons, could you share the share more details as mentioned before like configurations, code and errors so that we can determine what is causing the issue?

Comment: Updated the question with more details

Comment: My guess would be that there is something wrong in the token, could you share the full curl command that you used?

Comment: Updated the question with API Gateway

Comment: It worked when I added `allUsers` with Cloud Functions Invoker to the permissions to the function I am trying to invoke. So I am a bit confused here. When `allUsers` is added, the function becames public. Part of the reason I am using API gateway with firebase auth is to protect it against unauthorized calls. And for firebase auth to work, I had to add `allUsers`, making it public. My understanding was that the API gateway alone would be public while all the services that it invokes would be private.

Answer (score 0):

### Without ESP

Cloud functions need to be deployed **publicly** (with `allUsers`) to be able to use firebase authentication.

Be careful:

```
Unlike Google Sign-in above, your function is doing the authentication;
therefore, you will be billed for unauthenticated requests since the function must do work to validate the token.
```

[Link to relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#firebase_authentication)

### With ESP

If you want to use cloud functions with ESPv2 in front of it, you need to create a specific IAM for your ESP to be able to trigger **privately** your cloud functions.

```
To provide API management for Cloud Functions, you deploy the prebuilt ESPv2 container to Cloud Run.

You then secure your functions by using Cloud Functions IAM so that ESPv2 can invoke them.
```

[Link to relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions)